# Reading a maze file in python and printing out the maze line by line

Tags: python-2.7, list, maze, pyscripter

I am creating a maze traverser in Python. Initially I read the maze txt file as a list, but I am unable to print the maze line by line. We are given the number of rows and columns, the row and column of the entrance, and row and column of the exit.

What my ouput is:

```
    [['5', ' ', '5', ' ', '4', ' ', '1', ' ', '0', ' ', '1'], ['#', ' ', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', '#', '#', '#']]
```

what I am looking for:

```
    5 5 4 1 0 1
    # ###
    # # #
    # # #
    #   #
    # ###
```

---

My test code to print out the maze:

```
    #read MAZE and print 

    def readMaze(maze, filename):
        mazeFile = open(filename, "r")
        columns = mazeFile.readlines()
        for column in columns:
            column = column.strip()
            row = [i for i in column]
            maze.append(row)

    maze =[]
    readMaze(maze, "maze01.txt")

    print maze
```

Comment: You have nested lists. You need to use a `for` loop just like you have in your `readMaze` function to iterate over the top-level list, and on each element (which is a list of characters), use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate the characters into one string, print it, then move onto the next line.

Comment: okay thank you, I will edit it and let you know if i reach anymore issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your `maze` list is like this:

```
maze = [['5', ' ', '5', ' ', '4', ' ', '1', ' ', '0', ' ', '1'], ['#', ' ', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', '#', '#', '#']]
```

You could print it and have your desired print output using  `join` and a `for loop` like this example:

```
for i in maze:
    print("".join(i))
```

Output:

```
5 5 4 1 0 1
# ###
# # #
# # #
#   #
# ###
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply printing the whole list without ever iterating over it to print the characters how you want them. You need to use a `for` loop just like you have in your `readMaze` function to iterate over the top-level list, and on each element (which is a list of characters), use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate the characters into one string, print it, then move onto the next line

```
# your input list has multiple nested sub-lists
l = [
        ['5', ' ', '5', ' ', '4', ' ', '1', ' ', '0', ' ', '1'], 
        ['#', ' ', '#', '#', '#'], 
        ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'], 
        ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#'], 
        ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], 
        ['#', ' ', '#', '#', '#']
    ]

# so we iterate over them...
for sublist in l:
    print(''.join(sublist)) # ...and concatenate them together before printing
```

Output:

```
5 5 4 1 0 1  
# ###  
# # #  
# # #  
#   #  
# ###
```